# Obtener informacion de la gpu android, freq/modelo/version opengl etc/ los governor o similar

Tags: android, terminal, adb

pues queria saber si podia sacar esa informacion desde la terminal, en especial la frecuencia

busque informacion y lo que mas se acerca es este comando dumpsys | grep GLES

pero me hace falta información como la frequencia etc, encontre esta pagina de mali,pero la ruta no coincide con la de mi dispositivo
https://community.arm.com/graphics/f/discussions/2741/how-to-get-mali-gpu-s-frequency

pues tengo una mali t720,pero no se me es suficiente informacion gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podes ir a Menu -> opciones de desarrollador (devs tools) -> terminal del emulador (terminal emulator) y poner los siguientes comandos

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
cat /proc/meminfo
free
cat /proc/version
```

Adicionalmente podes la app que te dejo en [ESTE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.electricsheep.asi) link que tambien te muestra muchisima informacion sobre el dispositivo.